# Uploading zero size files to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using gdata python client for uploading/downloading files. I am not able to figure out how to upload zero sized files. Here is what I have.

```
#To update
file = gdata.data.MediaSource()
r = client.GetResourceById(resid)
client.UpdateResource(r, media=file, new_revision=True)

#To create a new file
file = gdata.data.MediaSource()
doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='file', title="Title")
r = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=uri, media=file)
```

I tried with removing media=None and also not including in the options. How can I make it work for zero sized files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the snippet for the `files.insert` method of the Drive API and not specify a `media_body` to create an empty file:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for gdata based solution. My code base is already with gdata and changing immediately to the new api is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Here is the test case if you want to try it out. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6joZvwOboPHbDdiNUxJT0pWVjg  Thanks